# Making an editable drop down box

Tags: html, css, select

How can I convert my existing custom drop down box into an editable drop down box. Is it possible that an input box can be placed where the drop box is? Is it possible to accomplish this without loading any heavy frameworks?

Here is the current HTML markup:

```
<html>

<style>
#select_box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 179px;
    clip:rect(2px 197px 19px 2px);
    top: -1px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#select_wrapper { 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 181px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    height: 21px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
</style>


<body>
                <div id="select_wrapper">
                    <select id="select_box">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                            <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                            <option value="THREE">THREE</option>
                            <option value="FOUR">FOUR</option>
                            <option value="FIVE">FIVE</option>
                            <option value="SIX">SIX</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No CSS3 specification does not support the detailed editing tag select
You can use the jQuery Selectbox plugin
http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/
A long time ago I had a same problem), the solution was found)
http://codepen.io/AntonEssenetial/pen/gGqel

CSS:

```
.pseselect {
    position: relative; // YOUR CONTAINER STYLE
    padding:;
    height:;
    border:;
    border-radius: ;
    background:;
    box-shadow:;
    font-size:;
    line-height:;
    cursor:;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.pseselect::after {
    position: absolute;
    top:
    right:
    display: block;
    width:
    height:
    background: url( YOUR IMG ) center no-repeat;
    content: "";
}

.options {
    position: absolute;  YOUR SLECT STYLE
    z-index: ;
    display: none;
    border: ;
    border-radius: ;
    background: white;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.options > div {
    padding:;   
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.options > div:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pseudo-select input-a">
  <div class="pseselect">Select</div>
  <div class="options">
     <div class="check" >Select</div>
     <div>Select</div>
     <div>Select</div>
     <div>Select</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $('.pseselect').click(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('.options').fadeIn('fast');
            });
            $('.options').mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut('fast');
            });
            $('.options > div').click(function() {
                $(this).closest('.pseudo-select').find('.pseselect').html($(this).html());
                $(this).closest('.pseudo-select').find('input').attr('value', $(this).attr('value'));
                $.each($(this).parent().children('div.check'), function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('check');
                });
                $(this).addClass('check');
                $(this).parent().fadeOut('fast');
            });
        }
    );
})(jQuery);
```